# Find out closest date in a date list django queryset python

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, django-queryset

I have a date list (date_list) that returns these dates.  I now need to find out what date is closest to another date(base_date).

I am using Python and Django to get this data

```
date_list = [datetime.date(2017, 6, 18), datetime.date(2018, 2, 4), datetime.date(2018, 2, 11), datetime.date(2018, 4, 23), datetime.date(2018, 6, 17)]

base_date = [datetime.date(2016, 4, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should be able to provide you the expected result for Python 3.

```
import datetime
date_list = [datetime.date(2017, 6, 18), datetime.date(2018, 2, 4), datetime.date(2018, 2, 11), datetime.date(2018, 4, 23), datetime.date(2018, 6, 17)]
base_date = [datetime.date(2016, 4, 7)]

closest_date = ''
lowest_time_delta = 99999999

for my_date in date_list:
    current_time_delta = abs((my_date - base_date[0]).total_seconds())
    if current_time_delta < lowest_time_delta:
         closest_date = my_date
         lowest_time_delta = current_time_delta

print (closest_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime                                                                                                                     
date_list = [datetime.date(2018, 2, 4),                                                                                             
             datetime.date(2018, 2, 11),                                                                                            
             datetime.date(2018, 4, 23),                                                                                            
             datetime.date(2017, 6, 18),                                                                                            
             datetime.date(2018, 6, 17)]                                                                                            

base_date = datetime.date(2016, 4, 7)                                                                                               

min_delta = min([abs(base_date - one) for one in date_list])                                                                        

closest_index = delta_list.index(min_delta)
```

date_list[closest_index] is the closest